# How to override CSS class with container div style?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .text-box {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="text-box">Hello</p>
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">
            <p class="text-box">Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div style="color: blue;"> 
            <p class="text-box">Hello</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

that produces

[image: HTML output with the word hello repeated three times in red with the second one also in bold font.]

The second paragraph works as expected because the paragraph element does not have a font-weight style to be overridden.

Is there a way to override the CSS priority order so the class on the third paragraph is overwritten by the style defined in the container div so that the text is blue?

Answer (score 1):

you're actually asking if you can override a CSS rule.
obviously the answer is NO.
CSS thinks in a correct way in my opinion, i.e. you can set rules on containers, but at the same time you can set them on children.
the priority states that the rules on children win over fathers, so if you don't need the CSS rule on the child, why set it?

Your goal with this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .text-box {
            color: red;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="text-box">Hello</p>
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">
            <p class="text-box">Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div style="color: blue;"> 
            <p >Hello</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give class to parent div and target the 3rd paragraph to give the color blue

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .text-box {
                color: red;
            }
            .text-boxDiv .text-box{
                color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="text-box">Hello</p>
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">
            <p class="text-box">Hello</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-boxDiv"> 
            <p class="text-box">Hello</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div> 
    <p class="text-box" style="color:blue;">Hello</p>
</div>
```

You will have to directly give the color property to the `p` tag inside your `div` tag

Or you could add a `class` to the `div` and do something like this:-

```
/* CSS */
.myDiv > p {
    color: blue;
}
```